# Probability that a person randomly chosen has $k$ apartments knowing the following weights

Tags: probability

You have to assign the probability that a randomly chosen person (in a population) has $k$ apartment knowing the following weights:
$$
q_k=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{c}{4} & \textrm{if} \ \ k=0 \\ 
\frac{c}{2^k} & \textrm{if} \ \ 1\leq k \leq 5 \\ 
0 & \textrm{if}\ \ k\geq6
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

1. For which values of $c$ the assigned weights define a probability function?
2. What's the probability that a randomly chosen person has at least 2 apartments?

I know that a function is a probability function (with events $E$) if:
$$
1.\ \ P(E) \geq 0 \ \ \ \textrm{for each} \  E\in \mathbb{F} \\
2.\ \ \textrm{if} \ \ E_h\cap E_k=\varnothing \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \sum_i P(E_i)=1
$$
but I don't know how I can approach this problem. What's $E$ in this case? How do I use those weights?

Comment: The sample space here is $\Omega =\mathbb{N}_0$, which is countable. A probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ should satisfy:
 $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) \geq 0, \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega$, and $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = \sum_{\omega\in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\})= 1$.

We are given $\mathbb{P}(\omega = k) = q_k$.

Comment: And so? How should I proceed?

Comment: sum up the probabilities and set the sum equal to 1: $c/4+\sum\limits_{k=1}^5 c\cdot  \frac1{2^k}=(1/4+1/2+1/4+1/2^3+1/2^4+1/2^5)\cdot c=1$

Comment: Ooooohh! Now it's all clear! Once that $c$ has been defined, I should take $c \cdot \sum_{k=2}^{5} \frac{1}{2^k}$ and divide it for $\Omega$?

Comment: There is nothing to divide. $P(X\geq 2)= c\cdot \sum\limits_{k=2}^5 \frac1{2^k}$ Or you use the converse probability $P(X\geq 2) =1-P(X\leq 1)=1-P(X=1)- P(X=0)=1-\frac{c}4-\frac{c}{2}=\frac5{13}$

Comment: Probability of an event is favorable cases divided for all possible cases, isn't it?

Comment: @ChuckTheYellow Yes, but $c\cdot \sum\limits_{k=2}^5 \frac1{2^k}$ is a **probability** and not the number of favorable cases. If you address  comment to a specific user put @ and username in front of your comment-like in this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your second property.  The sum of all the probabilities must be $1$, which allows you to find the value of $c$.  Then the chance somebody has at least two is one minus the chance they have zero or one.